# In oauth2, is expires_in is in seconds or miliseconds?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I got this sort of thing in oauth2

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 43200,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjExMzk2NGY3MDZiNGM0ZTJhYTFiM2M4NGQ1Y2YwYWRhMjA4OWIwNDc2ZjM3NjlhN2I1ZTBmZDNkN2YyM2IxYmUxNWE0N2Y0YTU4YmYzMzE1In0.eyJhdWQiOiIxNDQiLCJqdGkiOiIxMTM5NjRmNzA2YjRjNGUyYWExYjNjODRkNWNmMGFkYTIwODliMDQ3NmYzNzY5YTdiNWUwZmQzZDdmMjNiMWJlMTVhNDdmNGE1OGJmMzMxNSIsImlhdCI6MTU1NDc4NzQ3MSwibmJmIjoxNTU0Nzg3NDcxLCJleHAiOjE1NTQ4MzA2NzEsInN1YiI6IjMxOTgwMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJ0cmFkZSIsInByb2ZpbGUiXX0.blR3PYblZtYvd0VOnaePaUFu_dkE2yhbGgBLTHqXGuvaMC-57OhXaWNxLLjLzlHrL1bTJcMUYfRrBNhbpiLe9ln7FofuoRUfSm0IhBuvgX-5Le1k0KLd-1JdFW8Y1jIOYm8jGT7WdBRD3ykPoWAKcp_iuXgv2Ci_beii6W6ANX4BWShpekBuUfcKQoiXLNpmDWNt8SfbF4MDjDCs-Z81HAtzFr4P7lmMFugkqODOgVYg9VEhAdXWG56K8uTBmdc0v7w1Ahy7DE_wWzOMOA6JPq6qUvoIuz51I7LCLLhXUNeLXpELuXzREKqSbgZJb2KaZ67vbFYEM4dt8s67SKWfMv5KK7OPY6v0zB529m3r5H0wfvNOH7PNw782q9AmOSZc62yXCKijBNP-7XKsrzbK2LneVn8z_wDLJ3xjs7frppkQ0f-YAk3xmg8JJnPWDleLm4FUx32F2_MwPlN227ThgASi2N8jtRpkUgNFnOkBScDhEwpT5zqJK9H09pTkUIWdDCB7H5er0HR9qBK509qif4b9UGl1OHMnjQKyFQT36c5nGJCG05E0IRH8Mbax37Wv94Eb_53rpJwEWv_XkuT-N_wPEwf92VvwCUhoHxTK9a-p78NfCuroRQWARk4gdhZ9i_rCgQQEzlEk9EsiFl_bTcBgT7bU",
  "refresh_token": "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",
  "expire": 1554787516031
}
```

I changed the access token and refresh token a bit

Now there is expires_in 43200. Is that second or milisecond or years or what?

I used this code

```
Public Shared Function currentTimeStamp() As Int64
    Dim utime = (DateTime.UtcNow - unixEpoch()).TotalMilliseconds
    Return CLng(utime)
End Function

    Dim jtoken1 = JToken.Parse(jtoken2)
    Dim accesstoken = jtoken1.Item("access_token")
    Dim expirytime = jtoken1.Item("expires_in")
    Dim currentTimeStamp = jsonHelper.currentTimeStamp()
    Dim timeexpire = currentTimeStamp + CLng(expirytime)
    Dim refreshtoken = jtoken1.Item("refresh_token").ToString
    jtoken1.Item("expire") = timeexpire
```

That seems to be a bit wrong.

Is there any documentation that can clearly says it's seconds or milliseconds?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The `expires_in` is value in seconds. See [this section of the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1).

Comment: Do you have a source to back this up please?

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-4.2.2